# ERROR TypeError: error.json is not a function

Tags: json, angular, api, symfony

> core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: error.json is not a function
>       at CatchSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/user.service.ts.UserService.handelError
>   [as selector] (user.service.ts:58)
>       at CatchSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error
>   (catchError.js:104)
>       at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next
>   (map.js:82)
>       at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:90)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1226)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:425)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:424)
>       at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
>       at ZoneTask.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask
>   [as invoke]

when i want to add a form i had this error can someone know why.

**add.components.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../user.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-user',
  templateUrl: './add-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-user.component.css']
})
export class AddUserComponent implements OnInit {

  username: string ;
  email: string;

  errors= [];


  constructor(private _userService: UserService , private router: Router) { }

  addUser(username, email) {

    let user: any;
    user = {username: username, email: email};
    this._userService.addUser(user).subscribe(
      result => this.router.navigate(['/users']),
      err => this.errors.push(err)
    );

  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**form add.html**

```
<form (submit)="addUser(username,email)" class="well">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>username:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="add username"   [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" >
  </div>



  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="add email"  [(ngModel)]="email" name="email" >
  </div>

      <div *ngFor="let error of errors" class="alert alert-danger">
          <div>There is an error in :{{error.field}} field</div>
          <div>{{error.message}}</div>
        </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save</button>

</form>
```

**User.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import {User} from './User';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private uri= 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users';



  constructor(private http: Http, private authenticationService: AuthService  ) {}


  getUsers(): Observable<any[]> {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authenticationService.token });
    return  this.http.get(this.uri , {headers : headers}).map(res => <User[]> res.json() )
    .catch(this.handelError);

  }



  addUser(user: User) {
    const  headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authenticationService.token);
    return this.http.post(this.uri, JSON.stringify(user), {headers : headers})
    .map(res => res.json()).catch(this.handelError);
  }
```

Comment: FYI `Http` is deprecated, use `HttpClient` instead

Comment: Where is `handleError` code?

Comment: @charlietfl  the rest of code handleError
  private handelError(error: Response) {
    return Observable.throw(error.json().errors || 'server error');
  }

Comment: when i used @zgue  i have  ERROR TypeError:cannot read property  'post' of undefined

Comment: console.log out your error property in `handleError`. The error message is telling you the error property does not have a `json()` method.